# How to use async and awiat with CoreDispatcher correctly in UWP

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, async-await

I wanted to perform a Task in the background which involves changing UI state, and the task will start executing after the `MainPage` has loaded.

So I tried to use `CoreDispatcher` in the `Loaded` event handler like this:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () => DrawingBoard.Arrange());
}
```

And the `Arrange()` method :

```
public void Arrange()
{
    for(int i=1; i<95; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<85; j++)
            this.Children.Add(new Line{ /*initializing*/ });
}
```

Which gives this error:

*Error  CS4036  'IAsyncAction' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncAction' could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?)*

But if I don't use `async` and `await` keyword, there is no error except that the UI Thread become irresponsive during that method execution.

I don't get it how to use await and async with that `CoreDispatcher`. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with async await. You will see if you add `using System;` to the top it will also compile with async and await commands but still running slow.

Your method is already been called async, but it has to create 95 * 85 = 8075 line objects, doing this all on the UI thread. Since Line is a UI elemennt you can't do this in the background but adding such number of UI elements takes some times.

There are several ways of optimalisations possible but not knowing anything what you try to do its impossible to give advice how to get this working in a performant way